# Display size and color attributes in filter div

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I want to display my product size and color attributes in my filter div. How should i get all size and color attribute?

```
<?php
$categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories();
$count = is_array($categories)?count($categories):$categories->count();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(9); // not loading the product - just creating a simple instance
?>

<?php if ($count): ?>

<div class="filters">

    <dl class="filters_facet-list">
        <dt>
            <?php echo $this->__('Sub Category'); ?>
        </dt>

        <dd>
            <ol class="filters_option-list">
                <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
                    <?php if ($category->getIsActive()): ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category); ?>" <?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?>class="current"<?php endif; ?>>
                                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()); ?>
                                <span class="count"><?php echo $category->getProductCount(); ?></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ol>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <div class="">
        <?php echo $product->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);?>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: not for perticular product, I want all seze and color in  my filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all options of a attribute using this code -

```
$arrval = array();
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'your_attribute_here');
     foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) as $option) {
          $arrval[$option['label']] = $option['value'];
}
print_r($arrval);
```

Comment: Thanks @Piyush, But i want multiple attribute data, so how could I achieve this? like size, color, price

Comment: this code will work for dropdown type attributes, so you have to use same code for other dropdown type attributes.

Comment: How should i crate observer file for this? I want to create its json. JSON of all size,color,price.

Comment: why do you want to create observer?